# Play store - share button missing

Tags: google-play-store, share-menu

Am I blind or is there no share button so I cannot easily send somebody a link to some app from my phone? On a PC, I can copy a browser URL. I am pretty sure there was this share icon somewhere on the phone, but seems like it is no longer present.

[image]

Comment: In that menu I have a share button (PlayStore Version 13.8.16 235060107). May be you have set an app as default for share that is incompatible with PlayStore?

Comment: A bit weird but click on the developer name under the app name, it shows the list of apps by him/her, then and go back and click the dotted menu and Share item will be available.

Comment: @Alireza is correct and his comment is the correct answer. It's a bug. Google is not able to fix their store for 3 years now. Go figure.

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you go to Play Store from within settings > app >app info (depending upon your OS).

If you go directly to Play Store (not from app info of installed app) and search for the app, you can find the "share" option.

I noticed this ever since I upgraded to Pie in January.

One on the left is from within settings and on the right is direct search on Play Store.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Anybody can test if this was fixed in Android Q?

Comment: @Vitas at the very least, I just checked this is working properly on Google Pixel 3a, Android 12.

Comment: Still missing here... Google Pixel 2 XL with Android 11.

Comment: Yes. Still missing

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @CaptainCrunch it was correct at the time of writing. Google changes tons of things unfortunately :(