# Quick way to send a link to a Google Play store app via SMS

Tags: applications, google-play-store, sms, share-menu, hyperlinks

I feel like I'm not seeing something obvious.

I have several apps installed via the Google Play store on an Android device.  I want to send links via SMS to the appropriate Google Play store pages so the recipient can click on the links, have them open in the Google Play store app, and then decide if they want to install them.

This seems like obvious functionality, but I'm not seeing any way to do it in Android Nougat.

How can this be accomplished without installing a separate app for the task?

Comment: Might be related: [Play store - share button missing](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208788/44325)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I must be losing my mind.  Before writing the above question, I searched for a **Share** menuitem in the Google Play store.  I swear there was none.

Now, when I try the same thing, I see a **Share** menuitem that does exactly what I want: I can SMS a link for an app to someone else.

I can't explain why it wasn't displayed before.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I'm looking for that function and can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I came here for the same reason and it looks like you have to have the app installed before you can share a link to it. I hate modern UX.

Comment: I just tested by browsing random apps/games that I haven't installed and the share option is there.